# URL filtering and squid performance

Tags: squid

We are using squid web cache transparent proxy in our company and we usually have 450 users browsing during peak hours.  We get lists of URLs (upto even 1600 URLs per list) from the national telecom authority for blocking. We block them using Squid ACL with a black list file but we experience significant performance degradation as soon as we apply the ACL in squid.conf. What is the remedy of this problem? How can we block such huge number of URLs?.

Comment: Just FYI, you're probably not going to see a lot of sympathy or support based on the fact that you're implementing government-mandated censorship.  Might be time to look for a consultant or some other form of paid help, because I don't know anyone who'd help do what you're doing for free.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are experiencing a performance issue with squid's native ACL.

What version of squid are you using and what about specs on the box?

I am also curious if you are getting warnings in your logs when you reconfigure or restart squid when you apply new blacklists.

Keep in mind that `.somesite.com` also blocks all subdomains from the TLD down, so there is no need to have `crap.somesite.com` and `.somesite.com`, it will cause performance issues and flood out your log files. If this is an issue for you, make sure you parse out all the dupes/subs and keep only TLDs in there unless otherwise necessary to only have a sub blocked.

Also, have you tried the squid-prime blacklist from our website: http://squidblacklist.com?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the Squid configuration is reloaded, *everything* Squid does is paused.

I suggest to use ufdbGuard, a free URL filter for Squid.  When ufdbGuard reloads the URL database there is no negative effect for Squid or users browsing.  One can download ufdbGuard from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ufdbguard/) and [URLfilterDB](http://www.urlfilterdb.com).